# How can I import a Python class that is in two directories above and one below?

Tags: python, file, class, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I import a CustomerHelper class inside `customer_helper.py` from `customer_helper_test.py`? It's possible? I used `from ..helpers..tests..app.helpers.customer_helper import CustomerHelper` but it's invalid syntax.

Here is the folders organized:

```
program/
    app/
        helpers/
            customer_helper.py
            __init__.py
    __init__.py
    tests/
        helpers/
            customer_helper_test.py
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
    __init__.py
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Always strive to use absolute imports.

```
from program.app.helpers.customer_helper import CustomerHelper
```

If for some reason you absolutely can't, then

```
from ...app.helpers.customer_helper import CustomerHelper
```

Note that `app` must be a package regardless.

Comment: Both won't worked. The first solution raised `ImportError: No module named program.app.helpers.customer_helper` The second solution raised `ValueError: Attemped realtive import beyond toplevel package.`

Comment: @JohannGomes the first solution requires that `program` is in your `PYTHONPATH`. The second issue is why you shouldn't use relative imports! It will fail depending on where you run from. In this case you need to be at the project root `program/` not anywhere deeper.

Comment: Now it worked. I was deep in `program/tests`, that was the reason it wasn't working. Thanks, Adam.

Comment: @JohannGomes hopefully that **bolded** and *italicized* the line "Always strive to use absolute imports" for you! :)

Comment: @Adam, why not just edit your answer and bold+Italianate the line ;-)